# Random IllegalBlockSizeException when decrypting

Tags: java, encryption, raspberry-pi

I have some problem with decrypting text:

My backend often throws IllegalBlockSizeException during decryption:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

When I try again (1-3 times) finally it can decrypt the SAME text successfully and send the response to FE.

As I noticed it usually happens when I try to decrypt many (about 100) Strings in short time (2 requests arrive from FE, 15 record queried from db / request, 2 encrypted fields / record)

My server runs on a Raspberry Pi B+ with Raspbian. The problem is not present on "normal" PC.

The encryption class:

```
package bookmarks.common.encryption.base;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.net.util.Base64;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class DefaultEncryptor {
    private static final int SIZE = 16;
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";

    private static final Base64 BASE_64 = new Base64();

    private final Key key;
    private final Cipher cipher;

    public DefaultEncryptor(String password) {
        byte[] key = createKey(password);
        this.key = new SecretKeySpec(key, ALGORITHM);
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            log.error("Error creating encryptor.", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private byte[] createKey(String password) {
        if (password.length() < SIZE) {
            int missingLength = SIZE - password.length();
            StringBuilder passwordBuilder = new StringBuilder(password);
            for (int i = 0; i < missingLength; i++) {
                passwordBuilder.append(" ");
            }
            password = passwordBuilder.toString();
        }
        return password.substring(0, SIZE).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    public String encrypt(String text) {
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            byte[] base64 = BASE_64.encode(encrypted);
            return new String(base64, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            log.error("Error encryping value.", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    public String decrypt(String text) {
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] base64 = BASE_64.decode(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(base64);
            return new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            log.error("Error decrypting value.", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Any ideas what can cause the problem?**

Comment: If an exception is throw, log the relevant data to enable troubleshooting. At this point, based on your description of the events, you seem to be experiencing impossible behavior, so we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

Using only `AES` cipher without IV implies using `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`. This cipher and mode requires the input to decrypt being multiple of block size (128 bit)

```
  Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

The cipher complains about the input being not multiple of 16

> As I noticed it usually happens when I try to decrypt many (about 100) Strings in short time

What came to my mind (as James commented, it is my educated guess), the cipher object is not thread safe. With high confidence I'd say either

- the input is passed as not complete (you may want to log the input byte array length)
- there are multiple threads reusing the same cipher object

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the static constant BASE_64, what is not Thread-safe. When multiple requests arrived at the same time, spring-boot processed them parallel, and the base64 decoding returned corrupt result, and of course invalid data cannot be decrypted.